# Dynamically Creating HTML table from JS array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to dynamically create an HTML table using jQuery. I have a JS array filled with data.

I have tried the following and it doesn't work, nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

**Javascript code**

```
for(var i = 0; i < cycleArr.length; i++) {
    var strTable = "<tr>"
    for(var j = 0; j < cycleArr[i]; j++) {
        var strTable = strTable + "<td>";
        var strTable = strTable + cycleArr[i];
        var strTable = strTable + "</td>";
    }
    var strTable = strTable + "</tr>";
}
$('#model_table').append(strTable);
```

**HTML code**

```
<div id="model_table">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `cycleArr` is a 2-dimensional array (for everything else this code wouldn't make a lot of sense, but correct me if I'm wrong), I found the following issues with your code:

- You are comparing `j` with `cycleArr[i]` which is probably an array, instead of `cycleArr[i].length`.
- In the inner loop you are accessing `cycleArr[i]` instead of `cycleArr[i][j]`.
- You are overwriting your `strTable` variable in each iteration of the outer loop because you are assigning `<tr>` instead of appending it.
- You are declaring your variable `strTable` over and over again. It should be declared only once.
- You are inserting `<tr>`s and `<td>`s into a `<div>` instead of a `<table>`. While this may be intended, I assumed it is not.

Here is a working version of your code:

```js
var cycleArr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']];

var strTable = "";
for(var i = 0; i < cycleArr.length; i++) {
  strTable += "<tr>"
  for(var j = 0; j < cycleArr[i].length; j++) {
    strTable += "<td>";
    strTable += cycleArr[i][j];
    strTable += "</td>";
  }
  strTable += "</tr>";
}
$('#model_table').append(strTable);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="model_table">

</table>
```

Also, you wrote that you have a "JSON array", but it would appear you have a JS (JavaScript) array. A JSON array would be a string which encodes an array (you wouldn't be able to iterate over it before parsing it which makes it no longer JSON). I took the liberty to correct your post to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for answer Cherry. However this code seems to come in conflict with what I already have

Comment: I have created an html table , which is hardcoded in the html, and filled with data from another similar array using `$(document).ready(function(){ //load on read
 for(var i = 0; i < countryArr.length; i++) { 
  tr = $('<tr>'); //fills in table with details of countries
  tr.append("<td>" + countryArr[i].country_name + "</td>"); }
}); ` and this seems to overwrite the data that is acquired from cycleArr. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I put the code into one html file. Below is the code. Take note, that you need to allow the:

**strTable** - continue looping by adding += . Just simplify var strTable = strTable + "" from your code above.

The idea here is, you have column and row. First you'll loop the direction from left to right, then if the row is completed, you need to go to next row.

```
<div id="model_table">&npsp;</div> <!--  result here -->

<script type="text/javascript">   
   var cycleArr = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]];
   var strTable = '<table border="1" cellpadding="5">';
   for(var i = 0; i < cycleArr.length; i++) {
      strTable += "<tr>";
      for(var j = 0; j < cycleArr[i].length; j++) { 
         strTable += '<td>' + cycleArr[i][j] + '</td>'; 
       }
      strTable += "</tr>";
    }
   strTable += '</table>'; 

 document.getElementById('model_table').innerHTML = strTable;
</script>
```